# Operator [] overloading

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
class A
{
    public:
    A() {};
    void operator[](int x)
    {
    }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    A a;
    a.operator[](0);
    a[0];
}
```

Both calls work, but I want to know whether there is any difference. Is one more efficient than the other? Do other things happen(besides executing the code in the overloaded operator) in either case?

EDIT:
Is there a case why you would want to write a.operator instead of just []. What's the point of overloading if you're not using the short syntax?

Comment: In one case, you make it clear that there is an operator overloading, in the other, no, but it's less verbose. But in the compiled code, that's exactly the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The explicit `operator[]` (and any other explicit operator) is used in an inheritence heirarchy, where you are trying to call `operator[]` on a base class. You can't do that using the normal `[]`, as it would result in a recursive function call. ie; you might use something like this:

```
struct Base {
    void operator[] (int i) { }
};

struct Derived : public Base {
    void operator[] (int i) 
        { Base::operator[](i); }
};
```

Answer (score 5):

Both calls are identical. *All* the operators can be called with an explicit `.operator##` syntax, where `##` stands for the actual operator symbol.

It is the literal operators like `a + b` that are just syntactic sugar for `a.operator+(b)` when it comes to classes. (Though of course for primitive types that is not the case.)

Note that your []-operator is not very typical, since it is usually used to return a reference to something -- but it's up to you how to implement it. You're restricted to one single argument, though, unlike `operator()`.

Answer (score 2):

Other than having to type another 11 characters, there is no functional difference between the two.

Answer (score 1):

They are completely equivalent - just in once case C++ adds syntactic sugar that makes your code prettier. You can call all overloaded operators explicitly - the effect will be the same as when they are called implicitly and the compiler redirects calls to them.

Answer (score 1):

No there is **no difference** between both versions from performance point of view. `a[0]` is more readable.

Also, the `operator []` is *typically* defined as,

```
Type& operator[](const int x)
{
  return v[x];  // Type 'v' is member variable which you are accessing for array
}
```

Comment: If there is no intended return value (and type), then this answer would not be relevant.

Comment: @freedompeace, Return values are generally desired. Otherwise, we cannot do, `a[0] = a[1] = a[2] = ...;`.

Comment: @freedompeace: With the `typically` in place, I don't see any reason for the downvote. +1 to compensate a bad downvote.

Comment: @Als, *"selectively down-voting"* is an untraceable issue here in SO; which I am facing for sometime. This may or may not be the case. Anyways, thanks for support.

Comment: @iammilind, I feel for you. I get that too.